# How can I use OpenCL kernel to make accumulator?

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl, gpu, accumulator

```
    __kernel void cl_test(__global int* Number)
    {
       int id = get_global_id(0);
       if (id%5==0)
       {
           Number[0]++;
       }
       if (id%10==0)
       {
           Number[1]++;
       }
    }
```

As you can see, this is a very simple OpenCL kernel test code, what I want is to collect the number divisible by 5 and 10 in a range.

So here is the problem:
  since every work item's calculation is not pure parallel, the Number[0] or [1] in different items are related. 
    I can't get the correct result by reading the Number[0] or Number[1].

Is there any solution like the "global variable" in C++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use atomic operations.

```
__kernel void cl_test(__global int* Number)
{
   int id = get_global_id(0);
   if (id%5==0)
   {
       atomic_inc(Number);
   }
   if (id%10==0)
   {
       atomic_inc(&Number[1]);
   }
}
```

You should avoid using those as much as possible as atomic operations tend to be rather slow precisely because they make sure that it works correctly across threads.

Comment: Is this faster than a reduction algorithm or slower? Such as dividing size of target array by two at each step(for the results). Until there is only two elements in the final array.

Comment: Its depends on the GPU H/W On recent NVidia H/W  atomic operations are faster than a reduction algorithm. This was stated by an Nvidia architect at GTC 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Atomic add will  solve the summing problem

```
 __kernel void cl_test(__global int* Number)
    {
       int id = get_global_id(0);
       if (id%5==0)
       {
           atomic_add( Number, 1 );
       }
       if (id%10==0)
       {
           atomic_add( Number +1, 1 );
       }
    }
```